# 16.04 LTS on Alienware 15 R3

Tags: drivers, nvidia, alienware

I'm having an issue with random stuck cpu's when trying to get Ubuntu 16.04LTS going on a Dell Alienware 15 R3.  The computer does have the latest BIOS installed.  What I've done outside of the base install:

- Update the grub defaults in `/etc/default/grub` to be: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nogpumanager acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2013\""`
- Install nvidia-378 driver from the `ppa:graphics-driver` repo, along with prime select and bumble.  Set primary graphics to intel and verified that bumblebee is up and going successfully

When the system boots, it's stable - nothing seems to lockup.  The problem is that sometimes when I try to boot the system, it will get setup on a CPU hang.

Any suggestions on what else needs to be adjusted or tweaked to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer in this [github link](https://github.com/andrewwakeling/alienware-13-r3-ubuntu-16.04).

I noticed that you have written `acpi_osi=\"Windows 2013\"`, while the one in the github link has "Windows 2009".
Now, I'm unsure if your problem is pertaining to the `lspci` or `lshw`, but it is worth a try to set up the grub options properly.

Comment: tried it both ways actually - i was doing 2009 first, but I read somewhere else to try 2013 - didn't really notice a different